# C++ best file format to store lot of map coordinate

Tags: c++, file-io, file-format

I have implemented the [diamond-square algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond-square_algorithm) and I would like to store the map data in a file format. I'm mostly a beginner in C++, or at least in file reading and writing, so I have problem where to store a lot of data.

For example if I create a 65*65 map, then it's 16384 triangles, and each got 3 coordinates, 3 normal coordinates. Of course I can divide it for example to 4 32*32 map piece, but it's still many. Of course what really matters is the speed, there is no problem to write all the data in txt, but it is really slow, especially when I increase the map size.

I not really need a source, but something to read or learn from it.

Comment: Does the file need to be portable to other platforms?

Comment: No, now it's good for me if it Windows compatible. I still learning, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: You might want to have a Google around for 'triangle stripping'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try writing your coordinates as raw binary data. Check out `ostream::write` and `istream::read`. Alternatively, you can use the C-way of reading/writing files (with `fopen`, `fread`, `fwrite`, `fclose`), which will avoid a lot of casting. You'll have to open your files in binary mode for this to work.

If your file needs to be portable to other platforms, you'll have to consider things like [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), [struct padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment), integer sizes, etc.

Example:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>

struct Point {float x; float y; float z;};

bool operator==(const Point& p1, const Point& p2)
{
    return (p1.x == p2.x) && (p1.y == p2.y) && (p1.z == p2.z);
}

int main()
{
    Point p1 = {1, 2, 3};
    Point p2 = {4, 5, 6};

    std::ofstream out("data.dat", std::ios::binary);

    // Write Point as a binary blob of bytes

    // Lazy, but less portable way (there could be extra padding)
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&p1), sizeof(p1));

    // More portable way
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&p2.x), sizeof(p2.x));
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&p2.y), sizeof(p2.y));
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&p2.z), sizeof(p2.z));

    out.close();


    Point p3;
    Point p4;
    std::ifstream in("data.dat", std::ios::binary);

    // Read Point as a binary blob of bytes

    // Lazy, but less portable way (there could be extra padding)
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&p3), sizeof(p3));

    // More portable way
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&p4.x), sizeof(p4.x));
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&p4.y), sizeof(p4.y));
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&p4.z), sizeof(p4.z));

    assert(p1 == p3);
    assert(p2 == p4);
}
```

---

You may also be interested in the [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) library. It supports [binary archives](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/archives.html#archive_models), which may be significantly faster than text archives. It also knows how to serialize standard library containers.